# Do animals dream?

Tags: scripture, animals, dream

Human beings can experience atleast three states: Jagart (waking state), swapna (dream state) and sushupti (deep sleep).

How many states, among the three, can an animal experience? Are there any instances in scriptures that talk about the capability of dreaming in animals?

Comment: In no way, it falls under scientific speculation.

Comment: It is neither opinion based, I think scriptures surely talk about this.